# How do you usually handle the step-style project to react

Tags: reactjs

step means like this -> https://rsuitejs.com/en/components/steps

How do you usually handle the step-style project to react?

router? or something else?

I'm using only `antd`'s `step-component`.

But I'm still thinking about whether it's right to use only CSS framework.

I wonder how the others handled it.

+
case by case?

Comment: Are you looking for like this - https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/checkout/ ?
if it's ok, refere the source code - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a wizard. You only need to use a router if you wish for a user to be able to go to a particular step using a URL.

I suggest you use state. You can save the step number in a variable and conditionally render the appropriate markup.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1)

  return (
    step == 1 ? <><p>Step 1</p><button onClick={() => setStep(2)}>Go to Step 2</button></> : <p>Step 2</p>
  )
}

export default App
```